# Rails render buttons by really complex condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

My rails application members may have one of the two different roles: vip_lite and vip.
They can subscribe plan to renew their authorizing.

We also have four types plan: vip_lite/monthly, vip_lite/yearly, vip/monthly, vip/yearly.

A vip user might be subscribing one of the four plans, so does vip_lite.
Member with different roles and different plans can see different buttons in plan page(e.g. vip_lite and subscribing vip_lite/monthly member can see 'upgrade' button in vip plan page).

see the following sample code: (currently write in helper)

```
def plan_action_button(user)
  if user.vip? && user.subscribing_plan?(:vip_lite, :monthly)
    'button_a'
  elsif user.vip? && user.subscribing_plan?(:vip_lite, :yearly)
    'button_b'
  elsif user.vip? && user.subscribing_plan?(:vip, :monthly)
    'button_c'
  elsif user.vip? && user.subscribing_plan?(:vip, :monthly)
    'button_d'
  elsif user.vip_lite? && user.subscribing_plan?(:vip, :monthly)
    'button_e'
  elsif user.vip_lite? && user.subscribing_plan?(:vip, :yearly)
    'button_e'      

    ... and so on...
  end
end
```

So I have to deal with 2 * 4 = 8 conditions for each button in these pages. Is there a good pattern in rails for dealing with such case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting patterns that you can use here. Let's see what's repeated the most: `user.vip?`

Let's start the method with a guard clause

```
def plan_action_button(user)
  return 'whatever you need to return' unless user.vip?

  if user.subscribing_plan?(:vip_lite, :monthly)
   'button_a'
[...]
```

Then because there's a lot of combinaisons, it's hard to tell what changes and what remains the same for those buttons. Is it a I18n key? Is is the button tag with different links? Do you have access to those parts separately like `user.plan_name` and `user.plan_frequency`?

Answering those questions would help you a lot in seeing emerge a pattern.

Comment: The subscribing_plan?(xxx) combined with use.vip? or user.vip_lite? returns different buttons, so set guard clause for only user.vip? can not reduce the complexity I think. I've updated my code sample for more detailed description.